# Write two integers into high 4bits and lower 4 bits in a byte using java

Tags: java, io, binary

i have a java code to read a unsigned integer from high 4bit and another from lower 4bit

```
 byte[] value = getBytes(1);
 int first = (value[0] & 0xF0) >> 4;
 int second   = value[0] & 0x0F;
```

i have to write those 2 integers(first, second) back to new 1 byte using java.

please help me

Comment: You should use the OR operation. `b = (b | (first << 4)) + second`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically:

```
first << 4 | second
```

(assuming `first` and `second` were obtained with the original code, so they are in the range `0x0..0xF`).

However, the result of bitwise operations is `int` for `int` operands, so this expression is of type `int`. You need to cast it to `byte`:

```
byte b = (byte) (first << 4 | second)
```